# FormData append deep nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

Is it possible to append nested object to FormData?

```
let formData = new FormData();
let data = {
    title: 'title',
    text: 'text',
    preview: {
      p_title:'p title', 
      p_text: 'p text',
      files: [
        {file: File},
        {file: File}
      ]
    }
};
```

I tried this but this didn't help me:

```
for ( let dataKey in data ) {
  if (dataKey === 'profile_applicant') {
    for (let previewKey in data[dataKey]) {
      formData.append(`${previewKey}`, data[dataKey][previewKey]);
    }
  } else {
    formData.append(dataKey, data[dataKey]);
  }
}
```

Server console - console.log(req.body):

**first_name:** test

**last_name:** test

**date_of_birth:** test

**last_contact:** test

**files**: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: What types of data will be sent to the Backend? ex: string, int, boolean, file, blob etc. ? I posted an answer that I believe satisfies your use case, If it doesn't fit your use case, please comment so I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I can help, I did it in a simpler way and I believe it works for all hypotheses, please test.

If it doesn't fit your use case, please comment so I can edit my answer.

### Full Code:

```js
const parses = []

const fKey = key => ((function until(value, comp = value) {
    const result = value.replace(/\.([A-z0-9]*)(\.|$)/, '[$1]$2')

    return comp !== result ? until(result, value) : result
})(key))

function populateFormData(values, form = new FormData(), base = '') {
    Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
        const value = values[key]

        if (typeof value == 'string' ||
            typeof value == 'number' ||
            typeof value == 'boolean' ||
            value instanceof File ||
            value instanceof Blob)
        {
            form.append(fKey(`${base}${key}`), value)
            parses.push({
                key: `${fKey(`${base}${key}`)}`,
                value
            })
        } 
        else if (typeof value == 'object') 
        {
            populateFormData(value, form, `${base}${key}.`)
        }
    })
    
    return form;
}

populateFormData({
    title: 'Lucas',
    text: 'Is good :)',
    preview: {
        p_title: 'I am a P title',
        p_text: 'I am a P text',
        test: {
            example: 2,
            my: {
                obj: [
                    'eba',
                    {
                        hyper: 'text'
                    },
                    123
                ],
                yes: true
            }
        }
    }
})

console.log(parses)
```

Answer (score 0):

Files are particular objects, you have to append them like this:

```
files?.forEach(item => { formData.append('files[]', item.originFileObj) })
```

You should find your originFileObj in your file object, often sending all file can be a problem; It's important too to use [] on the append key, otherwise if files are multiple won't be found.